# Mock SiteSettingsProvider with Glass Mapper

Tags: glass-mapper, habitat, unit-testing

Does anyone know how I can go about mocking the SiteSettingsProvider in Habitat?

```
Item sitecoreItem= mvcContext.GetContextItem<Item>();

Item settingsItem= settingsProvider.GetSetting(sitecoreItem, "Settings", "General");

return  mvcContext.SitecoreService.GetItem<ISettings>(settingsItem.ID.Guid);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about mocking [SiteSettingsProvider](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/master/src/Foundation/Multisite/code/Providers/SiteSettingsProvider.cs) - then you should code against `ISiteSettingsProvider` abstraction over concrete impl.

Similar with `MvcContext` -> should use [IMvcContext](https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/blob/master/Source/Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc/Web/Mvc/IMvcContext.cs) abstraction instead.

That way your code would operate with logical contracts (instead of concrete impl) and become unit-testable.

Here is [an example with AutoFixture attribute to power abstract members generation (with NSubsitute)](https://making-it-faster.blog/2020/01/10/unit-testing/)

The test may look like:

```
    [AutoNSubsituteData, Theory]
    public void TestName(Item item, Item settingsItem, IMvcContext context, ISiteSettingsProvider settings)
    {
      mvcContext.GetContextItem().Returns(item);

      settingsProvider.GetSetting(sitecoreItem, "Settings", "General")
         .Returns(settingsItem);

      var sut = ...            
    }
```